# Update Several Rows in Another Table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking to update a few rows in a connected table using Entity Framework. What's the right way to do it?

```
UPDATE table2 SET v1=1, v2=2, v3=3, v4=4 WHERE ImageID = 1234 AND (v1 - v2) / (v3 - v4) == aspectRatio
```

The ImageID is being accessed using EF's linking through another table. For example, if images are in `table1`, then `image.table2.Where...`. I tried using the `Where()` to obtain all results and update them using a `foreach` before calling `SaveChanges()`, but I didn't think that would work and it hasn't seemed to...

Comment: Can you show your code that saves the data?

Comment: What do you mean save the data? `SaveChanges()`? That's just the EF method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I mean show the relevant code where you are doing your work.